# How can I fix UIView to stick at the top of the ScrollView that does not scroll?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIView in a ScrollView and the position of the UIView is at the top of the ScrollView.And I do not want to scroll the UIView according to the scrolling.So is it possible to do that? 
If yes then how?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to put your UIView inside the UIScrollView in a first place? Wouldn't it be easier just to have it above?

Comment: Sir, actually i will add some more views in that UIView using JSON.So it will be easy for my to expend the contentSize of the scrollView according to that UIView. @user2260054

Comment: thanks for the question same happened with me!

Answer (score 0):

Please Add UIView in self.view and Below UIView put scrolview then your requirement will full fill.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add your "static" view not to the `scrollview` but to `self.view` instead, and put the `scrollview` under it (either under in the Z axis or under in the X axis, that depends on your needs).

And bam, you're gold.

Answer (score -2):

To create UIView in UIScrollView stick to the top when scrolled up do:

```
- (void)createHeaderView:(UIView*)headerView {
_headerView = [headerView retain];
_headerViewInitialY = _headerView.frame.origin.y;
[_scrollView addSubview:_headerView];
_scrollView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
CGRect headerFrame = _headerView.frame;
headerFrame.origin.y = MAX(_headerViewInitialY, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
_headerView.frame = headerFrame;
}
```